# ActiveRecord querying to sort by two things - custom join?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I currently have the following which counts how many users belong to each service_provider:

```
User.where(service_provider_id: self.company.first.id).count
```

How would I do a custom join to also use the database rather than Ruby to find how users created after a specific date (i.e. 1/1/2016) belong to a service_provider?

I have this but it seems to need to be refactored due to the two wheres:

```
User.
  where(service_provider_id: self.company.first.id).
  where(created_at: Time.now.beginning_of_month..Time.now.end_of_month).
  count
```

Comment: Using multiple `where` methods just generates `AND` statements in sql; it's totally valid. Is it not giving you the results you expect?

Comment: This seems to be slightly faster when counting a few hundred thousand records (User.count(conditions: ["service_provider_id = ?", self.company.first.id]), over the first code line above. Consequently, how would I use this same technique by adding a second condition?

Comment: Interesting - I have never seen a benchmark comparison. between where and conditions. Conditions syntax is deprecated in favor of where, so I wouldn't recommend relying on it. Nevertheless you could do something like `User.where(service_provider_id: self.company.first.id, created_at: Time.now.beginning_of_month..Time.now.end_of_month).count`. Note that `User.where(service_provider_id: self.company.first.id, created_at: Time.now.beginning_of_month..Time.now.end_of_month).count` is equally valid.

Comment: If you're concerned with sql performance you can run `EXPLAIN` on your query. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#running-explain

Comment: How would I search for a record type A which belongs type B which belongs to Record type C. I'm trying to find all record As that belong to Record C?

Comment: You might be able to do that with a `has_many :through` association. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: They're belongs_to and not has_many. Was looking into delegates.